# how to use value return by boolean function in a new function python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found closely related topics but it did not answer my question. My `single_insert_or_delete` function returns `0`, `1`, or `2` and based on that value I want to use it in my `spelling_corrector` function, but so far I am having trouble, when I use `if value:` returned by the first function as an argument to my main python function it would not accept these value and python return None. What do I miss here?.

```
def spelling_corrector(s1,s2):
    out_list=[]

def single_insert_or_delete(s1,s2):
    a=s1.lower()
    b=s2.lower()
    if (len(a)==len(b))and (a==b):
        return 0
    elif len(a)>len(b):
        if b in a:
            if len(a)-len(b)==1:
                return 1
        else:
            return 2
    elif len(a)< len(b):
        if a in b:
            if len(b)-len(a)==1:
                return 1
        else:
            count =0
            for x in a:
                if x in b:
                    count+=1
            if len(b)-count==1:
                return 1
             else:
                return 2

    else:
        return 2
```

This is the main program

```
s1= s1.split() #This will return list
for x in s1:
    single_insert_or_delete(x,s2)
    if 0:
        out_list.append(x)
    elif 1:
        out_list.append(x)
    elif 2:
       out_list.append(x)
    else:    
       out_list.append(x)
    out_str=" ".join(out_list)
 return out_str
```

Test for output

```
 a="That is the Firs cas"
 b=['that','first','case','car']
 x=spelling_corrector(a,b)
 print(x)
```

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and try again.

Comment: check your logic in `single_insert_or_delete` there are many branches that don't return a value (and thus falls off the end, returning None), e.g. `single_insert_or_delete('abba', 'bb')`

Answer (score 0):

In Python there is no magic return value usage, you have to use it explicitly:

```
s1= s1.split() #This will return list
for x in s1:
    insert_or_delete = single_insert_or_delete(x,s2)
    if insert_or_delete == 0:
        out_list.append(x)
    elif insert_or_delete == 1:
        out_list.append(x)
    elif insert_or_delete == 2:
       out_list.append(x)
    else:    
       out_list.append(x)
out_str=" ".join(out_list)
return out_str
```